# How to write file in a different directory in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on Linux with python 2.7.x and I am running some programs python through terminal. I want the certain output should be written in a file located at *different* directory than my working directory. So I wrote this piece of code. However, what is happening is file `All.txt` is being created in current directory instead of the desired directory. Can someone help me where I went wrong?

```
ResultDir = '/pr/p1/ap11/' 
os.system('cd ' + ResultDir)
Outputname1 = 'All.txt'
Output1 = open(Outputname1, 'a')
Output1.write('hello' +'\n')
Output1.close()
```

Comment: Your call to `os.system` starts a new shell, changes its working directory, and then promptly destroys the shell. At no point is the working directory of your script set. (You can use `os.chdir()` if you want to do that.)

Answer (score 13):

Changing the current directory with `os.system` will not affect the Python process that’s running. Just open the file with its full path directly:

```
with open('/pr/p1/ap11/All.txt', 'a') as output:
    output.write('hello\n')
```

Comment: do I need to mention some output stream object closing statements? As I wrote in my code `Output1.close()`?

Comment: @b2850624 No, if you use the `with` statement like that, the file will be automatically closed.