# Can't save files to different dir in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, path

So I'm trying to convert a ton of txt files to csv and save them in a different folder.
I can covert them no problem, but they always save in the same folder they are read from.
I've tried joinpath, os.path.join, folder+filename, open (file 'w+' and 'x' and 'w').
The print statements in the covertToCSV function always give me the right folder and then show that the file doesn't get made in that folder.

...\nlps\11-CSV converted\CSV Combined

...\nlps\11-CSV converted\CSV Combined

...\nlps\11-CSV converted\Admission_Consult.csv

No matter what I try, I can't get it to save to the folder I want. This is getting hilarious. Links I've read through are at the bottom.

```
import sys
import csv
from pathlib import Path    


workspace = Path('.../nlps/11-CSV converted')
saveTo = Path('.../nlps/11-CSV converted/CSV Combined')

def openFiles(dir):
    filePaths = list(workspace.glob('*.txt'))
    return filePaths

# Converts given file to CSV with one column with tabs as delimiter
def convertToCSV(filePaths):
    for fileName in filePaths:
        with open(fileName, 'r') as in_file:
            stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
            lines = (line.split("\t") for line in stripped if line)
            fileName = fileName.with_suffix('.csv')
            newFile = workspace.joinpath('CSV Combined')
            file = newFile.joinpath(fileName)
            print(saveTo)
            print(newFile)
            print(file)
            with open('CSV Combined'/file, 'w+') as out_file:
                writer = csv.writer(out_file)
                writer.writerows(lines)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html

[Writing to a new directory in Python without changing directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935972/writing-to-a-new-directory-in-python-without-changing-directory)

[How to write file in a different directory in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071959/how-to-write-file-in-a-different-directory-in-python)

https://thispointer.com/how-to-create-a-directory-in-python/

[Creating files and directories via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700593/creating-files-and-directories-via-python)

Comment: try `os.chdir` before writing to file

Comment: Three dots `Path('.../` isn't a valid path.

Comment: @thebjorn, that's what I thought initially too, but I think they are just obfuscating their local filesystem with it's usernames and whatnot. I'm sorta concerned about this line `'CSV Combined'/file` performing a division operator on a string? Assuming it's just a copy error.

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL no that's just a pathlib operation.

Comment: I see, still confused at why he would want CSV Combined at the front of his path, and then appending the rest of what's in file. I would assume `open(saveTo/fileName, 'w+')` was what was desired.

Comment: I also tried saveTo/filename with no luck and yes the ... are obfuscation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me - using the `Path` attributes and methods to construct the new file's path.  It gets all the text files in the `workspace` and makes new files (with a  `'.csv'` extension) in the `saveto` path.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path    

workspace = Path(os.getcwd(),'output')
saveto = Path(workspace,'CSV Combined')
#saveto.mkdir()    # if it does not exist

for p in workspace.glob('*.txt'):
    new = Path(saveto,p.name)
    new = new.with_suffix('.foo')
    #print(f'save:{p} to {new}')
    with p.open() as infile, new.open('w') as outfile:
        # process infile here
        #outfile.write(processed_infile)
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```

---